# Resharper 'Ctrl + Alt Click' isn't working with visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, resharper

I installed vs 2017. And found that functional that I use every time isn't working anymore.Ctrl + alt click don't go to implementation ,it goes like 'ctrl click',to declaration.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

After some searching I found a solution . Need to uncheck visual studio settings 
[image]

Comment: wow, thanks! you saved me a bunch of time. I think this came with the latest update for me

Comment: Also helps when it just takes you to random locations when you ctrl+click

Comment: The setting is gone in my VS: 2017,15.1 (26403.7)

Comment: Updating to 15.5.6 it now shows the option, disabling it still doesn't make ReSharper alt+ctrl+left click go to impl.

Comment: @Peheje, in my case I had to unclick the option in Resharper (Options -> Search & Navigation -> Rich mouse navigation...), save and then reclick it and save again.

Comment: This solution does not work for me. I have tried unchecking/checking both repeatedly. I have Visual Studio version 15.6.7.

Comment: @Dranyar Try unchecking the option and then restart the visualstudio.

Comment: @MichaelSilver Thanks for the tip on forcing the 're-enabling' of the resharper rich mouse options. I had been following some tips on improving my VS performance. Once done my 'Ctrl Alt Click' stopped working. For some reason I had to uncheck the resharper options like you suggested. Save. Recheck. Save. Restart VS and it worked.  And yes, you need to disable the VS option as vborutenko describes too.

Comment: oh and it helps to clear the 'Resharper Cache' after making changes. Resharper -> Options -> Environment -> General, on the bottom there is a button Clear Caches. Click it and restart VS.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using ReSharper, please, be sure, that your license **is active**. It was the issue in my case. Ctrl+click did not worked with deactivated ReSharper license.