# Resharper 'Ctrl Click' isn't working with visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, resharper

Because of a Computer Change I recently had to install a fresh Visual Studio 2017 and the Resharper Ultimate Edition. After that, Ctrl-Click suddenly does no longer work as expected. Although the editor switches to "some" target, this target appears to be a bit "random".

Sometimes, though, it helps to simply step back with Ctrl-Minus to get to the desired target.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resharper 'Ctrl + Alt Click' isn't working with visual studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46792639/resharper-ctrl-alt-click-isnt-working-with-visual-studio-2017)

Answer (score 15):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46792639/resharper-ctrl-alt-click-isnt-working-with-visual-studio-2017#_=_). This also solved my Problem with a normal Ctrl-Click :)

Comment: It seems now VS 2017 natively supports go to definition by ctrl + click. Resharper also does that, so it navigates you to a definition 2 times in a row. First, to your desired definition and second seemingly to whatever happened to be under the cursor at the first step.